# CRC-ITU calculation in c#

Tags: c#, gps, crc16

I'm new to C#. I need to calculate CRC-ITU for the packet recieved from GPS devices. There is C code provided in the documentation but i don't know how to port it to C#, anyone could help me?

here is CRC-ITU algorithm in C :

```
static const U16 crctab16[] = 
{
    0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf,
    0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7,
    0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e,
    0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876,
    0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
    0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5,
    0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c,
    0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974,
    0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb,
    0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
    0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a,
    0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72,
    0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9,
    0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1,
    0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
    0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70,
    0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7,
    0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff,
    0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036,
    0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
    0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5,
    0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd,
    0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134,
    0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c,
    0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
    0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb,
    0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232,
    0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a,
    0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1,
    0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
    0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330,
    0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78,
};

    // calculate 16 bits CRC of the given length data.
U16 GetCrc16(const U8* pData, int nLength)
{
U16 fcs = 0xffff; // Initialize

while(nLength>0){
fcs = (fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ *pData) & 0xff];
nLength--;
pData++;
}
return ~fcs; // Negate
}

// Check whether the 16 bits CRC of the given length data is right.
 BOOL IsCrc16Good(const U8* pData, int nLength)
{
    U16 fcs = 0xffff;    // Initialize
    while(nLength>0){
        fcs = (fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ *pData) & 0xff];
        nLength--;
        pData++;
    }
    return (fcs == 0xf0b8);  // 0xf0b8 is CRC-ITU的"Magic Value"
}
```

I've also found C# code from http://ppcode.blogbus.com/logs/1656947.html but I don't know how to use it, here's the code

```
public class CrcITUTable
 {
  static ushort [] crctab16 =
   {
    0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf,
    0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7,
    0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e,
    0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876,
    0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
    0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5,
    0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c,
    0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974,
    0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb,
    0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
    0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a,
    0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72,
    0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9,
    0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1,
    0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
    0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70,
    0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7,
    0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff,
    0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036,
    0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
    0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5,
    0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd,
    0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134,
    0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c,
    0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
    0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb,
    0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232,
    0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a,
    0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1,
    0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
    0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330,
    0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78,
   };

  public CrcITUTable()
  {
   //
   // TODO: 在此处添加构造函数逻辑
   //
  }

  unsafe public ushort GetCrcITU_T(byte * pData,int nLength,out string crcCode)
  {
   ushort fcs=0xFFFF;
   ushort uRlt;
   string strTmp;
   while(nLength>0)
   {
    fcs= (ushort) ((ushort)(fcs>>8)^ crctab16[(fcs ^ *pData) &0xFF ]);
    nLength--;
    pData++;
   }

   uRlt=(ushort)~fcs;
   strTmp=uRlt.ToString("X4") ;
   crcCode=strTmp.Substring(2,2) + " " + strTmp.Substring(0,2);

   return uRlt;
  }

  unsafe public bool IsCrcITUGood_T(byte * pData,int nLength)
  {
   ushort fcs=0xFFFF;
   while(nLength>0)
   {
    fcs= (ushort) ((ushort)(fcs>>8)^ crctab16[(fcs ^ *pData) &0xFF ]);
    nLength--;
    pData++;
   }

   return (fcs==0xF0B8);
  }

 }
```

here is some example in the documentation :

full packet : 0x78 0x78 0x0D 0x01 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 0x89 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x00 0x01 0x8C 0xDD 0x0D 0x0A

Start bit : 0x78 0x78
lenght : 0x0D
Protocol No. : 0x01
Device ID : 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 0x89 0x01 0x23 0x45
Serial No. : 0x00 0x01
CRC Verify : 0x8C 0xDD
Stop Bit : 0x0D 0x0A

quote from documentation :

Device or server can judge the accuracy of data received with identifying code. Sometimes, because of the electronic noise or other interference, data will be changed a little in the transit process. In this case, identifying code can make sure the core or associated core do nothing with such kind of wrong data, which will strengthen the security and efficiency of system. This identifying code adopts CRC-ITU identifying method. The CRC-ITU value is from "Package Length' to "Information Serial Number" in the protocol (including "Package Length" and "Information Serial Number ").
If the receiver receives CRC wrong calculating information, then ignore it and discard this data package.

So anyone have idea how to get crc value from above example? thx

Answer (score 10):

Just follow the instructions of the document

> The CRC-ITU value is from "Package Length' to "Information Serial Number" in the protocol (including "Package Length" and "Information Serial Number ").

So we take the data from length to serial number

```
0x0D 0x01 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 0x89 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x00 0x01
```

now we use those set of numbers and pass it in to the CRC function. The code you linked uses unsafe pointers, I don't know if you need them or not as you did not post any of where you are using it. If you have the data in a byte array you can re-write the function to just pass in the byte array instead of the pointer, then the code will no longer need to be marked unsafe.

Here is my cleaned up version that uses bytes

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] dataPacket = { 0x78, 0x78, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x00, 0x01, 0x8C, 0xDD, 0x0D, 0x0A };
    var crc16 = GetCrc16(dataPacket, 2, 12);

    if (crc16 == ReadBigEndianUInt16(dataPacket, 14)))
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        //use packet.
    }

    Debugger.Break();
}

public static UInt16 ReadBigEndianUInt16(byte[] data, int offset)
{
    if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == true)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[2] {data[offset+1], data[offset]}            
        return BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 0);
    }
    else
    {
         return BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, offset);
    }
}

public static ushort GetCrc16(byte[] data, int offset, int length)
{
    ushort fcs = 0xFFFF;
    for (int i = offset; i < length + offset; i++)
    {
        fcs = (ushort)((ushort)(fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ data[i]) & 0xFF]);
    }

    return (ushort)(~fcs);
}

public static bool IsCrcITUGood(byte[] data, int offset, int length)
{
    ushort fcs = 0xFFFF;
    for (int i = offset; i < length + offset; i++)
    {
        fcs = (ushort)((ushort)(fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ data[i]) & 0xFF]);
    }

    return (fcs == 0xF0B8); //magic value
}

static ushort[] crctab16 = /*(snip)*/;
```

It appears that the CRC in the packet is stored in big Endian and C# code will produce little endian. So you will need to flip the two bytes of the CRC before you compare them.

---

As a side-note, I think that the `IsCrcITUGood` method is not from the gps spec. I think whatever you pulled this code example from had a special set of bytes to make the CRC always equal `0xF0B8`. In your data it gives you the expected CRC value. I could find no way to make the CRC equal `0xF0B8`

Answer (score 1):

None of the codes above worked for me but I inspired myself from them to get my working version of the code.

```
private static ushort GetCrc16(byte[] pData, int offset, int length)
    {
        ushort[] crctab16 = { 0X0000, 0X1189, 0X2312, 0X329B, 0X4624, 0X57AD, 0X6536, 0X74BF, 0X8C48, 0X9DC1, 0XAF5A, 0XBED3, 0XCA6C, 0XDBE5, 0XE97E, 0XF8F7, 0X1081, 0X0108, 0X3393, 0X221A, 0X56A5, 0X472C, 0X75B7, 0X643E, 0X9CC9, 0X8D40, 0XBFDB, 0XAE52, 0XDAED, 0XCB64, 0XF9FF, 0XE876, 0X2102, 0X308B, 0X0210, 0X1399, 0X6726, 0X76AF, 0X4434, 0X55BD, 0XAD4A, 0XBCC3, 0X8E58, 0X9FD1, 0XEB6E, 0XFAE7, 0XC87C, 0XD9F5, 0X3183, 0X200A, 0X1291, 0X0318, 0X77A7, 0X662E, 0X54B5, 0X453C, 0XBDCB, 0XAC42, 0X9ED9, 0X8F50, 0XFBEF, 0XEA66, 0XD8FD, 0XC974, 0X4204, 0X538D, 0X6116, 0X709F, 0X0420, 0X15A9, 0X2732, 0X36BB, 0XCE4C, 0XDFC5, 0XED5E, 0XFCD7, 0X8868, 0X99E1, 0XAB7A, 0XBAF3, 0X5285, 0X430C, 0X7197, 0X601E, 0X14A1, 0X0528, 0X37B3, 0X263A, 0XDECD, 0XCF44, 0XFDDF, 0XEC56, 0X98E9, 0X8960, 0XBBFB, 0XAA72, 0X6306, 0X728F, 0X4014, 0X519D, 0X2522, 0X34AB, 0X0630, 0X17B9, 0XEF4E, 0XFEC7, 0XCC5C, 0XDDD5, 0XA96A, 0XB8E3, 0X8A78, 0X9BF1, 0X7387, 0X620E, 0X5095, 0X411C, 0X35A3, 0X242A, 0X16B1, 0X0738, 0XFFCF, 0XEE46, 0XDCDD, 0XCD54, 0XB9EB, 0XA862, 0X9AF9, 0X8B70, 0X8408, 0X9581, 0XA71A, 0XB693, 0XC22C, 0XD3A5, 0XE13E, 0XF0B7, 0X0840, 0X19C9, 0X2B52, 0X3ADB, 0X4E64, 0X5FED, 0X6D76, 0X7CFF, 0X9489, 0X8500, 0XB79B, 0XA612, 0XD2AD, 0XC324, 0XF1BF, 0XE036, 0X18C1, 0X0948, 0X3BD3, 0X2A5A, 0X5EE5, 0X4F6C, 0X7DF7, 0X6C7E, 0XA50A, 0XB483, 0X8618, 0X9791, 0XE32E, 0XF2A7, 0XC03C, 0XD1B5, 0X2942, 0X38CB, 0X0A50, 0X1BD9, 0X6F66, 0X7EEF, 0X4C74, 0X5DFD, 0XB58B, 0XA402, 0X9699, 0X8710, 0XF3AF, 0XE226, 0XD0BD, 0XC134, 0X39C3, 0X284A, 0X1AD1, 0X0B58, 0X7FE7, 0X6E6E, 0X5CF5, 0X4D7C, 0XC60C, 0XD785, 0XE51E, 0XF497, 0X8028, 0X91A1, 0XA33A, 0XB2B3, 0X4A44, 0X5BCD, 0X6956, 0X78DF, 0X0C60, 0X1DE9, 0X2F72, 0X3EFB, 0XD68D, 0XC704, 0XF59F, 0XE416, 0X90A9, 0X8120, 0XB3BB, 0XA232, 0X5AC5, 0X4B4C, 0X79D7, 0X685E, 0X1CE1, 0X0D68, 0X3FF3, 0X2E7A, 0XE70E, 0XF687, 0XC41C, 0XD595, 0XA12A, 0XB0A3, 0X8238, 0X93B1, 0X6B46, 0X7ACF, 0X4854, 0X59DD, 0X2D62, 0X3CEB, 0X0E70, 0X1FF9, 0XF78F, 0XE606, 0XD49D, 0XC514, 0XB1AB, 0XA022, 0X92B9, 0X8330, 0X7BC7, 0X6A4E, 0X58D5, 0X495C, 0X3DE3, 0X2C6A, 0X1EF1, 0X0F78 };
        ushort fcs = 0xFFFF;
        ushort fcs2 = 0xFFFF;
        for (int i = offset; i < length + offset; i++)
        {
            fcs = (ushort)((fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ pData[i]) & 0xff]);
        }
        return ((ushort)((fcs & fcs2) ^ fcs2));
    }

    public static ushort GetCrc16Inverted(byte[] pData, int offset, int length)
    {
        return ReadBigEndianUInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes(GetCrc16(pData, offset, length)), 0);
    }

    private static ushort ReadBigEndianUInt16(byte[] data, int offset)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == true)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[2] { data[offset + 1], data[offset] };
            return BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, offset);
        }
    }


[Test]
    public void Crc_Itu_16_Should_Be_Generated_Correctly()
    {
        byte[] dataPacket = { 0x78, 0x78, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x00, 0x01, 0x8C, 0xDD, 0x0D, 0x0A };
        var crc = ConcoxTrackerManager.GetCrc16Inverted(dataPacket, 2, 12);
        byte[] crcErrorExpected = { 0x8C, 0xDD };
        var crcErrCheckFlipped = BitConverter.ToUInt16(crcErrorExpected, 0);
        Assert.True(crc  == crcErrCheckFlipped);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found very few links on CRC 16 calculation but found one of the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20872042/2952062) in javascript helpful.

In case anyone is looking for the same CRC 16 calculation using python, have created the public gist along with working python fiddle example:

https://gist.github.com/mrudang-vora/6a0767be085a275c0df3

Hope it helps someone.