# Need help in correcting issues in CRC-ITU check method written in Javascript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gps, crc

We are trying to code GPS device listener on Javascript.

While doing this, we are unable to develop the right script for the CRC-ITU error check. The explanation for the crc code generation from protocol document is as below

> A check code may be used by the terminal or the server to distinguish
>   whether the received information is error or not. To prevent errors
>   occur during data transmission, error check is added to against data
>   misoperation, so as to increase the security and efficiency of the
>   system. The check code is generated by the CRC-ITU checking method.
>   The check codes of data in the structure of the protocol, from the
>   Packet Length to the Information Serial Number (including “Packet
>   Length” and “Information Serial Number”) , are values of CRC-ITU. CRC
>   error occur when the received information is calculated, the receiver
>   will ignore and discard the data packet.

We referred to the C code sample given in the protocol document -

```
// calculate the 16-bit CRC of data with predetermined length. 

U16 GetCrc16(const U8* pData, int nLength) 
{ 
   U16 fcs = 0xffff; // initialization 
   while(nLength>0)
   { 
     fcs = (fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ *pData) & 0xff]; 
     nLength--; 
     pData++; 
   } 
   return ~fcs; // negated 
}
```

the array crctab16 is the array same as mentioned in our code sample

```
    Incoming data string comes in following format

    Example of data packet sent by the terminal 78 78 0D 01 01 23 45 67 89 01 23 45 00 01 8C DD 0D 0A

    Explanation

    Start Bit - 0x78 0x78
    Length - 0x0D
    Protocol - 0x01
    Terminal ID - 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 0x89 0x01 0x23 0x45
    Serial No - 0x00 0x01
    Error - 0x8C 0xDD
    Stop Bit - 0x0D 0x0A
```

Our Javascript code below

```
var net = require('net');

net.createServer(function(socket) 
{

    socket.setEncoding('hex');

    // New client connection event
    socket.on('connect', function(data)

    // Incoming data event
    socket.on('data', function(data) 
    {
        console.log("Client said: " + data); // server log
        data_p = data.substring(4,28);
        err_code = crc16(data_p);
        console.log("error: " + err_code);
    });


    // Disconnect event
    socket.on('end', function()
    {
        //Log it to the server output
        console.log("someone left us." + socket.remoteAddress);
    });

}).listen(3006);

console.log("TCP ECHO SERVER STARTED ON 3006");





function crc16(buf)
{

    var crcTable = 
    [
        0X0000, 0X1189, 0X2312, 0X329B, 0X4624, 0X57AD, 0X6536, 0X74BF, 0X8C48, 0X9DC1, 0XAF5A, 
        0XBED3, 0XCA6C, 0XDBE5, 0XE97E, 0XF8F7, 0X1081, 0X0108, 0X3393, 0X221A, 0X56A5, 0X472C, 
        0X75B7, 0X643E, 0X9CC9, 0X8D40, 0XBFDB, 0XAE52, 0XDAED, 0XCB64, 0XF9FF, 0XE876, 0X2102, 
        0X308B, 0X0210, 0X1399, 0X6726, 0X76AF, 0X4434, 0X55BD, 0XAD4A, 0XBCC3, 0X8E58, 0X9FD1, 
        0XEB6E, 0XFAE7, 0XC87C, 0XD9F5, 0X3183, 0X200A, 0X1291, 0X0318, 0X77A7, 0X662E, 0X54B5, 
        0X453C, 0XBDCB, 0XAC42, 0X9ED9, 0X8F50, 0XFBEF, 0XEA66, 0XD8FD, 0XC974, 0X4204, 0X538D, 
        0X6116, 0X709F, 0X0420, 0X15A9, 0X2732, 0X36BB, 0XCE4C, 0XDFC5, 0XED5E, 0XFCD7, 0X8868, 
        0X99E1, 0XAB7A, 0XBAF3, 0X5285, 0X430C, 0X7197, 0X601E, 0X14A1, 0X0528, 0X37B3, 0X263A, 
        0XDECD, 0XCF44, 0XFDDF, 0XEC56, 0X98E9, 0X8960, 0XBBFB, 0XAA72, 0X6306, 0X728F, 0X4014, 
        0X519D, 0X2522, 0X34AB, 0X0630, 0X17B9, 0XEF4E, 0XFEC7, 0XCC5C, 0XDDD5, 0XA96A, 0XB8E3, 
        0X8A78, 0X9BF1, 0X7387, 0X620E, 0X5095, 0X411C, 0X35A3, 0X242A, 0X16B1, 0X0738, 0XFFCF, 
        0XEE46, 0XDCDD, 0XCD54, 0XB9EB, 0XA862, 0X9AF9, 0X8B70, 0X8408, 0X9581, 0XA71A, 0XB693, 
        0XC22C, 0XD3A5, 0XE13E, 0XF0B7, 0X0840, 0X19C9, 0X2B52, 0X3ADB, 0X4E64, 0X5FED, 0X6D76, 
        0X7CFF, 0X9489, 0X8500, 0XB79B, 0XA612, 0XD2AD, 0XC324, 0XF1BF, 0XE036, 0X18C1, 0X0948, 
        0X3BD3, 0X2A5A, 0X5EE5, 0X4F6C, 0X7DF7, 0X6C7E, 0XA50A, 0XB483, 0X8618, 0X9791, 0XE32E, 
        0XF2A7, 0XC03C, 0XD1B5, 0X2942, 0X38CB, 0X0A50, 0X1BD9, 0X6F66, 0X7EEF, 0X4C74, 0X5DFD, 
        0XB58B, 0XA402, 0X9699, 0X8710, 0XF3AF, 0XE226, 0XD0BD, 0XC134, 0X39C3, 0X284A, 0X1AD1, 
        0X0B58, 0X7FE7, 0X6E6E, 0X5CF5, 0X4D7C, 0XC60C, 0XD785, 0XE51E, 0XF497, 0X8028, 0X91A1, 
        0XA33A, 0XB2B3, 0X4A44, 0X5BCD, 0X6956, 0X78DF, 0X0C60, 0X1DE9, 0X2F72, 0X3EFB, 0XD68D, 
        0XC704, 0XF59F, 0XE416, 0X90A9, 0X8120, 0XB3BB, 0XA232, 0X5AC5, 0X4B4C, 0X79D7, 0X685E, 
        0X1CE1, 0X0D68, 0X3FF3, 0X2E7A, 0XE70E, 0XF687, 0XC41C, 0XD595, 0XA12A, 0XB0A3, 0X8238, 
        0X93B1, 0X6B46, 0X7ACF, 0X4854, 0X59DD, 0X2D62, 0X3CEB, 0X0E70, 0X1FF9, 0XF78F, 0XE606, 
        0XD49D, 0XC514, 0XB1AB, 0XA022, 0X92B9, 0X8330, 0X7BC7, 0X6A4E, 0X58D5, 0X495C, 0X3DE3, 
        0X2C6A, 0X1EF1, 0X0F78
    ];


    crcX = parseInt("FFFF",16);
    cr1 = parseInt("FF",16);
    cr2 = parseInt("FFFF",16);
    i = 0;

    while(i < buf.length)
    {
        str = buf.substring(i,i+4);
        console.log("str "+str);
        str_hex = parseInt(str,16);

        j = (crcX ^ str_hex) & cr1;
        crcX = (crcX >> 8) ^ crcTable[j] ;

        i = i + 4;
    }

    crcX = ~crcX;

    console.log("crcX - " + crcX.toString(16));
    return crcX;
}
```

Please find below pairs of inputs strings and the corresponding code that should be generated by the function crc16

```
    78780d01035889905017664600267bf90d0a - 7bf9
    78780d010358899050176646002ab1950d0a - b195
    78780d010358899050176646002ba01c0d0a - a01c
```

Please help us find the errors in our code.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~` in the original code only worked because it was a 16-bit type.  You should use `crcX = crcX ^ 0xffff` instead of `crcX = ~crcX`.

Also your `buf.substring(i,i+4)` and `i = i + 4` is wrong.  You need to process one byte at a time, which is two hexadecimal digits.  Those should both be `i+2`.

Answer (score 2):

There are some `crc` packages on `npm`, but they may not work for you, I create a new one that is just a copy of `c` code from your link to document.

Install `crc-itu` from terminal:

```
npm install crc-itu
```

app.js

```
var crc16 = require('crc-itu').crc16;

var crcInHex = crc16('0d0103588990501766460026', 'hex').toString(16);
console.log(crcInHex); // will print 7bf9
```

you can also try with these values, note: `crc16(data).toString(16) => crc`

```
start          data              crc   end
-------------------------------------------
7878   0d0103588990501766460026  7bf9  0d0a
7878   0d010358899050176646002a  b195  0d0a
7878   0d010358899050176646002b  a01c  0d0a
```

Comment: E:\Codes\app>npm install git://github.com/damphat/crc-itu.git     npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong      result (git://github.com/damphat/crc-itu.git)

I am getting this Git error.

Comment: I want to share this algorithm to the world, via `npm install crc-itu`, if you have time, help me test again by `npm install crc-itu`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '192.168.1.151';
var PORT = 5023;


function protocall_decorder(data,sbit,plength,protono,ebit){

// Login data   
if(plength.toString('hex') == '0d') {
    var ret = crc16Ccitt(data.slice(2,14));
    var err_code = ret;
    console.log(err_code.toString(16));
    plength = new Buffer('05','hex');
    var res = sbit + plength + protono + data.slice(12,14) + err_code.toString(16) + ebit;

    data = "device_imei: " + parseInt(data.slice(4,12).toString('hex'));
    console.log(data);


    res = new Buffer(res)
    var dataArr = {response:res, type:"login", data:data};
}
/*
// Location data
else if(plength == '1F') {
    var res = '787805' + ***** +  data.slice(60,64) + data.slice(24,28) +'D9DC' + '0D0A';
    dataArr = data.substring(2);
}

// Alarm data
else if(plength == '25') {
    dataArr = data.substring(2);
}
// Heart Beat
else if(plength == '08') {
    dataArr = data.substring(2);
}
// Undefined data length
*/
else {
    var dataArr = {response:"error", data:plength};
}


return dataArr;

}

// The sock object the callback function receives UNIQUE for each connection
net.createServer(function(sock) {

// We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

// Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
sock.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
    // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server


//////////////// MySQL | Begin ////////////////////
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'lahirutm',
    database : 'gt06n'
});
con.connect();


var sbit = data.slice(0,2);
var plength = data.slice(2,3);
var protono = data.slice(3,4);
var ebit = data.slice(-2)

if(sbit.toString('hex') == '7878') {
    var res = protocall_decorder(data,sbit,plength,protono,ebit);
    if(res['response'] != 'error') {
        sock.write(res['response']);
        var response = res['response'];
    }
}
else {
    console.log('Undefined protocol data');
}

console.log(response); // Write data to socket

var message  = {start_bit: sbit, packet_length: plength, proto_no: protono, serial:'*', end_bit: ebit};
var query = con.query('INSERT INTO incoming_data SET ?', message,
//var message = {data: data} 
//var query = con.query('INSERT INTO row_data SET ?', message,
function(err, result) {
        // Neat!
});
console.log(query.sql);

var message = {data: data} 
var query = con.query('INSERT INTO row_data SET ?', message,
function(err, result) {
        // Neat!
});
console.log(query.sql);
con.end();
///////////////  MySQL | Begin ////////////////

});

// Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
sock.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
});

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);



/**
* CRC functions
*/

var crc16CcittTableReverse = [
    0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329B, 0x4624, 0x57AD, 0x6536, 0x74BF,
    0x8C48, 0x9DC1, 0xAF5A, 0xBED3, 0xCA6C, 0xDBE5, 0xE97E, 0xF8F7,
    0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221A, 0x56A5, 0x472C, 0x75B7, 0x643E,
    0x9CC9, 0x8D40, 0xBFDB, 0xAE52, 0xDAED, 0xCB64, 0xF9FF, 0xE876,
    0x2102, 0x308B, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76AF, 0x4434, 0x55BD,
    0xAD4A, 0xBCC3, 0x8E58, 0x9FD1, 0xEB6E, 0xFAE7, 0xC87C, 0xD9F5,
    0x3183, 0x200A, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77A7, 0x662E, 0x54B5, 0x453C,
    0xBDCB, 0xAC42, 0x9ED9, 0x8F50, 0xFBEF, 0xEA66, 0xD8FD, 0xC974,
    0x4204, 0x538D, 0x6116, 0x709F, 0x0420, 0x15A9, 0x2732, 0x36BB,
    0xCE4C, 0xDFC5, 0xED5E, 0xFCD7, 0x8868, 0x99E1, 0xAB7A, 0xBAF3,
    0x5285, 0x430C, 0x7197, 0x601E, 0x14A1, 0x0528, 0x37B3, 0x263A,
    0xDECD, 0xCF44, 0xFDDF, 0xEC56, 0x98E9, 0x8960, 0xBBFB, 0xAA72,
    0x6306, 0x728F, 0x4014, 0x519D, 0x2522, 0x34AB, 0x0630, 0x17B9,
    0xEF4E, 0xFEC7, 0xCC5C, 0xDDD5, 0xA96A, 0xB8E3, 0x8A78, 0x9BF1,
    0x7387, 0x620E, 0x5095, 0x411C, 0x35A3, 0x242A, 0x16B1, 0x0738,
    0xFFCF, 0xEE46, 0xDCDD, 0xCD54, 0xB9EB, 0xA862, 0x9AF9, 0x8B70,
    0x8408, 0x9581, 0xA71A, 0xB693, 0xC22C, 0xD3A5, 0xE13E, 0xF0B7,
    0x0840, 0x19C9, 0x2B52, 0x3ADB, 0x4E64, 0x5FED, 0x6D76, 0x7CFF,
    0x9489, 0x8500, 0xB79B, 0xA612, 0xD2AD, 0xC324, 0xF1BF, 0xE036,
    0x18C1, 0x0948, 0x3BD3, 0x2A5A, 0x5EE5, 0x4F6C, 0x7DF7, 0x6C7E,
    0xA50A, 0xB483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xE32E, 0xF2A7, 0xC03C, 0xD1B5,
    0x2942, 0x38CB, 0x0A50, 0x1BD9, 0x6F66, 0x7EEF, 0x4C74, 0x5DFD,
    0xB58B, 0xA402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xF3AF, 0xE226, 0xD0BD, 0xC134,
    0x39C3, 0x284A, 0x1AD1, 0x0B58, 0x7FE7, 0x6E6E, 0x5CF5, 0x4D7C,
    0xC60C, 0xD785, 0xE51E, 0xF497, 0x8028, 0x91A1, 0xA33A, 0xB2B3,
    0x4A44, 0x5BCD, 0x6956, 0x78DF, 0x0C60, 0x1DE9, 0x2F72, 0x3EFB,
    0xD68D, 0xC704, 0xF59F, 0xE416, 0x90A9, 0x8120, 0xB3BB, 0xA232,
    0x5AC5, 0x4B4C, 0x79D7, 0x685E, 0x1CE1, 0x0D68, 0x3FF3, 0x2E7A,
    0xE70E, 0xF687, 0xC41C, 0xD595, 0xA12A, 0xB0A3, 0x8238, 0x93B1,
    0x6B46, 0x7ACF, 0x4854, 0x59DD, 0x2D62, 0x3CEB, 0x0E70, 0x1FF9,
    0xF78F, 0xE606, 0xD49D, 0xC514, 0xB1AB, 0xA022, 0x92B9, 0x8330,
    0x7BC7, 0x6A4E, 0x58D5, 0x495C, 0x3DE3, 0x2C6A, 0x1EF1, 0x0F78
];


var crc16CcittStart = 0xFFFF;
var crc16CcittXorout = 0xFFFF;

function crc16Reflected(buf, crc_in, table) {
    var crc16 = crc_in;

    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        crc16 = table[(crc16 ^ buf[i]) & 0xff] ^ (crc16 >> 8);
    }

    return crc16 & 0xFFFF;
}

function crc16Ccitt(buf) {
    return crc16Reflected(buf, crc16CcittStart, crc16CcittTableReverse) ^ crc16CcittXorout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found very few links on CRC 16 calculation but found the [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20872042/2952062) in javascript helpful.

In case anyone is looking for the same CRC 16 calculation using python, have created the public gist along with working python fiddle example:

https://gist.github.com/mrudang-vora/6a0767be085a275c0df3

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using java

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String sample_string ="78 78 0D 01 01 23 45 67 89 01 23 45 00 01 8C DD 0D 
  0A";
  String[] data_packet = packet.split(" ");
  String[] pdata = Arrays.copyOfRange(data_packet, 2, data_packet.length - 4);
  //pdata will be from "packet-length" to "Information Serial Nummber"
  //discarding "start-bit" from start and "Error-check" and "Stop Bit" from end
  //actual pdata[]={0D,01,01,23,45,67,89,01,23,45,00,01};
  String error_code = crc16(pdata);
  System.out.println("================>Error_code:" + error_code);

  }
  public String crc16(String[] pdata) {

    int[] crcTable
            = {
                0X0000, 0X1189, 0X2312, 0X329B, 0X4624, 0X57AD, 0X6536, 0X74BF, 0X8C48, 0X9DC1, 0XAF5A,
                0XBED3, 0XCA6C, 0XDBE5, 0XE97E, 0XF8F7, 0X1081, 0X0108, 0X3393, 0X221A, 0X56A5, 0X472C,
                0X75B7, 0X643E, 0X9CC9, 0X8D40, 0XBFDB, 0XAE52, 0XDAED, 0XCB64, 0XF9FF, 0XE876, 0X2102,
                0X308B, 0X0210, 0X1399, 0X6726, 0X76AF, 0X4434, 0X55BD, 0XAD4A, 0XBCC3, 0X8E58, 0X9FD1,
                0XEB6E, 0XFAE7, 0XC87C, 0XD9F5, 0X3183, 0X200A, 0X1291, 0X0318, 0X77A7, 0X662E, 0X54B5,
                0X453C, 0XBDCB, 0XAC42, 0X9ED9, 0X8F50, 0XFBEF, 0XEA66, 0XD8FD, 0XC974, 0X4204, 0X538D,
                0X6116, 0X709F, 0X0420, 0X15A9, 0X2732, 0X36BB, 0XCE4C, 0XDFC5, 0XED5E, 0XFCD7, 0X8868,
                0X99E1, 0XAB7A, 0XBAF3, 0X5285, 0X430C, 0X7197, 0X601E, 0X14A1, 0X0528, 0X37B3, 0X263A,
                0XDECD, 0XCF44, 0XFDDF, 0XEC56, 0X98E9, 0X8960, 0XBBFB, 0XAA72, 0X6306, 0X728F, 0X4014,
                0X519D, 0X2522, 0X34AB, 0X0630, 0X17B9, 0XEF4E, 0XFEC7, 0XCC5C, 0XDDD5, 0XA96A, 0XB8E3,
                0X8A78, 0X9BF1, 0X7387, 0X620E, 0X5095, 0X411C, 0X35A3, 0X242A, 0X16B1, 0X0738, 0XFFCF,
                0XEE46, 0XDCDD, 0XCD54, 0XB9EB, 0XA862, 0X9AF9, 0X8B70, 0X8408, 0X9581, 0XA71A, 0XB693,
                0XC22C, 0XD3A5, 0XE13E, 0XF0B7, 0X0840, 0X19C9, 0X2B52, 0X3ADB, 0X4E64, 0X5FED, 0X6D76,
                0X7CFF, 0X9489, 0X8500, 0XB79B, 0XA612, 0XD2AD, 0XC324, 0XF1BF, 0XE036, 0X18C1, 0X0948,
                0X3BD3, 0X2A5A, 0X5EE5, 0X4F6C, 0X7DF7, 0X6C7E, 0XA50A, 0XB483, 0X8618, 0X9791, 0XE32E,
                0XF2A7, 0XC03C, 0XD1B5, 0X2942, 0X38CB, 0X0A50, 0X1BD9, 0X6F66, 0X7EEF, 0X4C74, 0X5DFD,
                0XB58B, 0XA402, 0X9699, 0X8710, 0XF3AF, 0XE226, 0XD0BD, 0XC134, 0X39C3, 0X284A, 0X1AD1,
                0X0B58, 0X7FE7, 0X6E6E, 0X5CF5, 0X4D7C, 0XC60C, 0XD785, 0XE51E, 0XF497, 0X8028, 0X91A1,
                0XA33A, 0XB2B3, 0X4A44, 0X5BCD, 0X6956, 0X78DF, 0X0C60, 0X1DE9, 0X2F72, 0X3EFB, 0XD68D,
                0XC704, 0XF59F, 0XE416, 0X90A9, 0X8120, 0XB3BB, 0XA232, 0X5AC5, 0X4B4C, 0X79D7, 0X685E,
                0X1CE1, 0X0D68, 0X3FF3, 0X2E7A, 0XE70E, 0XF687, 0XC41C, 0XD595, 0XA12A, 0XB0A3, 0X8238,
                0X93B1, 0X6B46, 0X7ACF, 0X4854, 0X59DD, 0X2D62, 0X3CEB, 0X0E70, 0X1FF9, 0XF78F, 0XE606,
                0XD49D, 0XC514, 0XB1AB, 0XA022, 0X92B9, 0X8330, 0X7BC7, 0X6A4E, 0X58D5, 0X495C, 0X3DE3,
                0X2C6A, 0X1EF1, 0X0F78
            };

    int crcX = 0xFFFF;
    int cr1 = 0xFF;
    int cr2 = 0xFFFF;
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    while (i < pdata.length) {
        String str = pdata[i];

        int str_hex = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);

        j = (crcX ^ str_hex) & cr1;
        crcX = (crcX >> 8) ^ crcTable[j];

        i++;
    }
```